# decode snappy messages using Bigtable cbt

Tags: bigtable

I have some data in bigtable, but the messages are all snappy encoded. Does anyone know a way to decode it?

```
cbt -project project-1 -instance test read events count=10 prefix=test123
```

This gives me output but its snappy encoded

Comment: Hi, Is the issue resolved?